# How to convert an .avsc Avro schema file into an .avdl Avro schema file as part of a Maven build?

Tags: maven, avro, confluent-schema-registry, avro-tools, avsc

- The [Confluent Schema Registry Maven Plugin](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/maven-plugin.html) can not register `.avdl` Avro schema files in a schema registry, only `.avsc` Avro schema files.
- The [Apache Avro Maven plugin](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/getting-started-java/) can not convert `.avdl` Avro schema files into `.avsc` Avro schema files.

How can I convert an `.avsc` Avro schema file into an `.avdl` Avro schema file as part of a Maven build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can convert `.avdl` Avro schema files into `.avsc` Avro schema files by leveraging the Maven [exec-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) plugin:

```
<profile>
    <id>avsc</id>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${avro-tools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>avsc-generation</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.apache.avro.tool.Main</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>idl2schemata</argument>
                        <!-- path to input .avdl file -->
                        <argument>path/to/AvdlFile.avdl</argument>
                        <!-- path to output directory -->
                        <argument>path/to/output-directory</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: Please fix the question, in the title you ask for `.avsc` -> `.avdl` conversion but it seems you asked for the opposite.